# How to programatically show a tooltip of a pane in CMFCStatusbar?

Tags: c++, mfc, tooltip

I have a `CMFCStatusBar` which has an icon indicating status of an application. As the status changes i need to show the changed status for few seconds as a tool tip. How to show this programmatically?

Comment: Showing a tooltip in response to something other than a mouse-over event is a very weird bit of UI. I don't recommend it. Why not just display the text directly in the status bar next to the icon?

Comment: Thats a good idea but i need to get users attention that the state has been changed so i thought showing a tooltip is a better way

Comment: If they notice a tooltip popping up, they're just as likely to notice an icon or text string changing to something else. The trick is that something happens "down there" that they notice out of their peripheral vision.